# Calling a method to add lines to a text file in java

Tags: java, text, java-io

I want to be able to call a method like this

```
public void Printer(String ToPrint)throws IOExcpetion{
BufferedWriterName.write(ToPrint);
}
```

That would just add a text line to an already created file.
But this code needs to be in the same method

```
FileWriter Write=new FileWriter("c:\\filename.txt");
BufferedWriter BufferedWriterName =new BufferedWriter(Write);
```

I am worried that it will create a new file each time the method is called if the above code is present. Is there any method that when called will only print a new line to the .txt file?
I'm a real beginner in this field. I've never created text files from java before, so a completely different approach would be fine.

Comment: Keep the file open. Opening and closing it for every line is extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 4):

Open the `File` in append mode by passing `true` to `FileWriter` constructor.

```
FileWriter Write=new FileWriter("c:\\filename.txt",true);
```

[public FileWriter(String fileName,boolean append)  throws IOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)

> Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name with a boolean indicating whether or not to append the data written.

Answer (score 0):

`I've never created text files from java before, so a completely different approach would be fine.` - Ok, there you go: You can use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) to simplify this

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
import com.google.common.io.Files;

public class FileAppendTest {

  /**
   * @param args
   * @throws IOException 
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("c:\\filename.txt");
    Files.append("\nline of text to be appended", file, Charsets.UTF_8);
  }
}
```

Comment: Err, line terminators *terminate* the line. That means they go at the end, not the beginning.

Comment: @EJP usage of `\n` depends whether old file had empty line at the end or not. If it had (which is normally true), `\n` should be used at the end of the appended line. And anyway, that's not the point of this answer, point is to show different, nicer, soapproach :)

Comment: Nonsense. Unless the file *began* with a newline and *didn't* end with one, your code is incorrect.

Comment: EJP, do you state, that codes taken from code samples posted here should be blindly copy-pasted to production code without any sort of testing them and maybe tuning to the ones purpose?

Comment: I have no idea where you got that ridiculous statement, but it certainly wasn't from me. Don't put words into my mouth.

Comment: It would be better if you avoided jumping to conclusions and using straw-man arguments altogether. I've been on the Internet and its predecessors for over 25 years and I assure you that every time I've seen a question that starts 'so are you saying', 'do you state', etc., the answer is invariably 'no'. It's poor technique. Avoid it. For one thing it's so easy to refute.